# Google переходы

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, get

если зайти сюда: http://www.google.com/doodles/thanksgiving-day-2013-korea
то откроется сайт с дудлами.
попробуйте полистать и посмотреть на массив get и страницу.
как добиться настолько плавного перехода со страницы на страницу? О_О

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гуглим [ajax window.history.pushstate](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ajax+window.history.pushstate#q=ajax+window.history.pushstate) и читаем!

Comment: примерчиков бы....гугл говорит что-то плохое

Comment: Примерчики по аналогичным запросам, не я же их буду набрасывать)

Comment: а мне кажется если использовать нормальный фреймворк типа angularjs для создания сайта. то такие эффекты легко достижимы.